# Pausing JavaScript Asynchronous Loop for some time

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have a problem with pausing asynchronous JS loop from execution for some period of time.

I need it to pause, for example every 45th iteration so I came up with a simple code to help me determine when it happens:

```
if (i > 1)
{
    var numba = i / 45;

    if (isInteger(numba))
    {
        document.write('TIMEOUT START <br>');
        setTimeout(function(){document.write('TIMEOUT END<br>');}, 540000);
    }
}

function isInteger(x)
{
        return x % 1 === 0;
}
```

And my async loop code is following:

```
var num = 150;

var asyncLoop = function(o)
{
    var i=0;

    var loop = function(){
        i++;
        if(i==o.length){o.callback(); return;}
        o.functionToLoop(loop, i);
    } 
    loop();//init
}


asyncLoop({
    length : num,
    functionToLoop : function(loop, i)
    {
            if (i==0){}
            loop();

    },
    callback : function(){
    }    
});
```

First I tried to place this code for pausing loop inside the loop function however that didn't work and now I partly understand why. However every other way I tried failed also. 
Does anyone know how to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you want to pause?

Comment: There seems to be no relationship between the 2 pieces of code. In addition, asyncLoop is not a loop, it's recursively calling itself.

Comment: It's because the loop is getting data about shares number on facebook of my posts (via graph.facebook.com), and when I have about 1k posts to query it seems that after 300 urls runned through graph.facebook.com i need it to "cool" for a few minutes

Comment: there is certainly a better way to do it other than pausing. I don't knwo what that way is, but please seek it. pausing async doesn't seem like a good time

Comment: @digitalfresh in the way i placed them, true but if you place, this code inside `functionToLoop : function(loop, i)` it partly works - it runs this JS timeout function and outputs "TIMEOUT START" but it doesnt stop loop from executing (because i suppose this timeout also is being executed asynchronously)

Comment: You must not call `document.write` from a timeout!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a snippet I whipped up.
It will call `functionToLoop` `loops` times, pausing for `pauseTimeout` milliseconds each `pauseAt` runs, then calls `callback` at the end.

```
function loopWithPause(functionToLoop, callback, loops, pauseAt, pauseTimeout) {
    var n = 0;
    function start() {
        if(n + pauseAt > loops) pauseAt = loops- n;
        for(var i = 0; i < pauseAt; i++) {
            functionToLoop(n + i);
        }
        n += pauseAt;
        if(n == loops) callback();
        else setTimeout(start, pauseTimeout);
    }
    start();
}
```

Example:

```
loopWithPause(function(i){console.log(i)}, function(){console.log('done!')},10, 2, 2000);
```

Outputs:

```
0 
1 
(2 second pause)
2 
3 
(2 second pause)
4 
5 
(2 second pause)
6 
7 
(2 second pause)
8 
9
done!
```

For your scenario the call will probably be:

```
loopWithPause(functionToLoop, callback, 150, 45, 540000);
```

Answer (score 0):

This does what you're asking. Perhaps you can adapt it to your need. Paste it into your JavaScript console and watch it run forever.

```
var printNumbers = function(startingAt) {
  var end = startingAt + 45;
  for (i = startingAt; i < end; i++)
  {
    console.log(i)
  }
  window.setTimeout(function() { printNumbers(end); }, 1000)
}


printNumbers(0)
```

It's almost recursive, except that the recursion happens via the event loop with the time-out.

This carries state forward via the variable, to be used next time the function runs (alternatively use a global variable or closure to contain the state between function executions). It's the only way to do something like this, because JavaScript is single-threaded and you can't 'pause' without making the whole runtime grind to a halt.